# Add include from an external file

Tags: php

I would like to include a site name from a file called sitename.php I have tried

```
$thisPage='include "sitename.php" '; ?>
```

and get error report. I also need to add the file into

```
 include("../../../EngineerLocation/sitename.php");
```

instead of the words sitename I would like to include the sitename from the php file

Comment: how is **site name** stored in **sitename.php** ??

Comment: sitename.php only contains the words COUNTY PRINT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either include an actual php file:

```
// sitename.php
<?php
$thisPage = "Page Name";

// otherpage.php
<?php
include("sitename.php");
echo $thisPage;
```

Or use [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents)

```
// sitename.txt
Page Name
// otherpage.php
<?php
$thisPage = file_get_contents("sitename.txt");
```

To include a file using the name in sitename, do the following:

```
<?php
$thisPage = file_get_contents("sitename.txt");
include("../../../EngineerLocation/{$thisPage}.php");
```

Comment: <?php $thisPage = "file_get_contents(sitename.php)";?>tried this but it only showed file_get_contents(sitename.php) at the top of the page

Comment: That looked sensible but first one showed nothing second showed word reports which suggests the file is not found it is in the same folder as the page

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, the filename has to be inside quotes: `<?php $thisPage = file_get_contents("sitename.php") . " Reports";?>`

Comment: Well done works fine many thanks. Any idea how <?php include("../../../EngineerLocation/COUNTY PRINT.php"); ?> the words County Print can be added by including sitename.php

Comment: That is brilliant thank you.Will save lots of time adding new accounts.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/sitename.php");
```

Comment: But how does that fit into <?php $thisPage="Reports"; ?>